# Dynamically change ListCell's width of ListView in JavaFX

Tags: css, listview, javafx, width

this is the interface of a chat app using javaFX. The chat window is a ListView component and I'm using CSS to polish it a little bit. Here are the CSS and the screenshot:
[image]

```css
.list-cell {
  display: inline-block;
  -fx-min-width: 50px;
  -fx-background-color: lightyellow;
  -fx-background-radius: 30px;
  -fx-border-radius: 20px;
  -fx-border-width: 2px;
  -fx-border-style: solid;
  -fx-border-color: #666666;
}
.list-cell:empty {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
  -fx-border-width: 0px;
}
```

The problem is that I want to change the width of each listCell depending on the length of text. I've tried to set `minWidth` `prefWidth` (for example 50px) in the CSS file or using `listView.setCellFactory` but nothing happens. The length does not change at all. I wonder that can I change the length of each cell in a listView like that or not (or in order to do that I must use something like an HBox/VBox/seperator...)

Comment: You mean you want the list to appear jagged? The right edge being in different positions according to the length of the text in the row?

Comment: Looking again I realize you mean the main text, not the user list to the left, which makes more sense. 
I believe the list cell ignores all sizing, as it is laid out by the `ListView`, so you would probably have to provide a custom cell factory and style the inner node (e.g. a `TextFlow`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cell factory that sets the graphic to a `Label`, and style the label. E.g.:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FormattedListCell extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().addAll("One", "Two", "Three", "Four");

        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>() {
            private final Label label = new Label();
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    label.setText(item);
                    setGraphic(label);
                }
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(listView, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("formatted-list-cell.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and modify the stylesheet:

```css
.list-cell .label {
  display: inline-block;
  -fx-min-width: 50px;
  -fx-background-color: lightyellow;
  -fx-background-radius: 30px;
  -fx-border-radius: 20px;
  -fx-border-width: 2px;
  -fx-border-style: solid;
  -fx-border-color: #666666;
}
.list-cell:empty .label {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
  -fx-border-width: 0px;
}
```

You may need to actually style the list cell (as well as the label inside it) to get the exact style you want, but this should get you started.

[image]

Here is a more complete CSS file, which uses `-fx-background` so that the text color will automatically adjust, manages the selection color, and also adds some styles to the list cell itself:

```css
.list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
    -fx-padding: 0 ;
}

.list-cell .label {
  display: inline-block;
  -fx-background: lightyellow;
  -fx-background-color: -fx-background ;
  -fx-background-radius: 30px;
  -fx-border-radius: 20px;
  -fx-border-width: 2px;
  -fx-border-style: solid;
  -fx-border-color: #666666;
  -fx-padding: 12px ;
}
.list-cell:empty .label {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
  -fx-border-width: 0px;
}
.list-cell:selected .label {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar ;
}
```

[image]